# Subspace of $\textrm{End}(W)$ spanned by actions in a representation $G\curvearrowright W$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be a field; let $V = K^n$. Consider the action of $G=\operatorname{SL}_n(K)$ on $W=\bigwedge^r V$. What is the dimension of the subspace of $\operatorname{End}(W)$ spanned by the elements of $\operatorname{GL}(W)$ corresponding to elements of $G$?

Answer (score 5):

The representation $W = \bigwedge^r V$ is irreducible (when non-zero) by Vadim Alekseev's comment below. (Also this can be seen by elementary arguments, using that if $V$ has basis $v_{1}, \ldots, v_n$, then $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ acts transitively on the canonical basis $v_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{i_r}$ of $W$.)

Hence by Jacobson's Density Theorem, the image of $G$ in $\mathrm{GL}(W)$ is dense and the linear span of the matrices representing $G$ is the full endomorphism algebra $\mathrm{End}(W)$. In particular, the dimension is $\binom{n}{r}^2$.

Comment: How do you get this conclusion from the Artin-Wedderburn theorem (... or from the Density Theorem, though I take that must be easy)?

Comment: Ah: I think I need that $K$ is algebraically closed to do it using Artin–Wedderburn. Then it is routine: the subalgebra $A$ of $\mathrm{GL}(W)$ spanned by the matrices representing $G$ has $W$ as a simple module. So it is a simple algebra and so, by Artin–Wedderburn, it is a complete matrix algebra over a division ring containing $K$. But this division ring is a finite extension of an algebraically closed field, so is $K$ itself.

Comment: @MarkWildon: I was thinking similarly and ran into the question what to do about the division ring, but then the literature helped: by Proposition II.2.8 in Jantzen's “Representations of Algebraic Groups”, the $G$-endomorphisms of a highest weight module $L$ over _any_ field $K$ are trivial: $\operatorname{End}_G(L)=K$. Now, $W=\bigwedge^r V$ for $\operatorname{SL}_n/K$ is a highest weight module, so we're good in this situation: by Jacobson's density theorem the action $G$ generates the whole $\operatorname{End}(W)$.

Comment: @Vadim Alekseev. Thank you! This does it. Also I have a more elementary way to see that $W$ is irreducible: will add to my answer.

Comment: But you can assume wlog that $K$ is algebraically closed, no?

Comment: Yes, for polynomial representations of general linear and special linear groups, by the general `characteristic-free' theory. But I think some argument is needed: for instance, the cyclic group $C_3 \cong \mathbb{F}_4^\times$ has an irreducible $2$-dimensional representation from the vector space isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_4 \cong \mathbb{F}_2^2$, but here the image is a $2$-dimensional subalgebra of $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{F}_2^2)$.

Comment: You may assume that $K$ is algebraically closed if the representation is "absolutely irreducible", that is remains irreducible over the algebraic closure. This is not the case in the counter-example above, but is the case in the original question.